# Straight line while calculating efficient frontier of two-stock portfolio

Tags: python, pandas, finance, quantitative-finance, portfolio

I have a school assignment where we get the prices of Amazon and Pfizer and need to calculate the portfolio stdev and mean return of a portfolio with the two stocks and then plot the datapoints in order to get an efficient frontier.

There are 20 portfolios. Portfolio 1 is 0% Amazon, 100% Pfizer; Portfolio 2 is 5% Amazon, 95% Pfizer; Portfolio 3 is 10% Amazon, 90% Pfizer; ... Portfolio 20 is 0% Amazon, 100% Pfizer.

I tried writing a python script to compute the efficient frontier but for some reason I keep getting a straight line: (see picture)[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzmkG.png)

Searching online this means I'm likely doing something wrong. I honestly have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code I've written:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


# Read in the data
df = pd.read_csv('../data.csv')

'''
Plot Amazon and Pfizer stocks in the standard diagram with the mean return on the y-
axis and the standard deviation of returns on the x-axis. Plot the potential
combinations of stocks with a share in Amazon 0 <= wAmazon <= 1 and a
share in Pfizer wP f izer = 1−wAmazon with a step size resolution of 0.05 in the
same diagram (the efficient frontier).
'''

#Calculate standard deviation for Amazon and Pfizer
df["AMZN"]    = df["AMZN"].pct_change()
df["PFIZER"]  = df["PFIZER"].pct_change()

stdev_amzn    = df["AMZN"].std()
stdev_pfizer  = df["PFIZER"].std()

#Get the mean log returns for Amazon and Pfizer
return_amzn   = df["AMZN"].mean()
return_pfizer = df["PFIZER"].mean()



#Calc correlation between Amazon and Pfizer
correlation   = df["AMZN"].corr(df["PFIZER"])
talj = stdev_pfizer**2 - (stdev_amzn * stdev_pfizer * correlation)
namn = stdev_amzn**2 + stdev_pfizer**2 - (2 * stdev_amzn * stdev_pfizer * correlation)
print("Minimum variance portfolio: ", talj/namn)

#Calculate portfolio return and standard deviation for different weights btwn 0 and 1 with increments of 0.05
returns  = []
stdevs   = []
for x in np.arange(0, 1.00, 0.001):
    w_amzn   = x
    w_pfizer = 1 - x
    returns.append(return_amzn * w_amzn + return_pfizer * w_pfizer)
    stdevs.append(np.sqrt((stdev_amzn**2 * w_amzn**2) + (stdev_pfizer**2 * w_pfizer**2) + (2 * correlation * stdev_amzn * stdev_pfizer * w_amzn * w_pfizer)))

#Plot the monthly return of each stock if x% of the portfolio is in amazon and 100% - x% is in pfizer on the y axis
#and the standard deviation of returns on the x axis
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=stdevs, y=returns, name='Efficient Frontier'))
fig.update_layout(title='Efficient Frontier', xaxis_title='Standard Deviation', yaxis_title='Mean Return')
fig.show()
```

If you have any idea what could be wrong I'd greatly appreciate the help

Comment: See what picture?

Comment: What value do you calculate for `correlation`?

Comment: If "correlation" happens to have a value of +1.0 or -1.0, a straight line is exactly what your (returns, stdevs) list amounts to.

Comment: Also, are the rows of your `df["AMZN"]` and `df["PFIZER"]` daily returns, or are they prices? You need the standard deviation and correlation of the (preferably logarithmic) *returns*, not the absolute prices.

Comment: @ES100 0.96 seems pretty high intuitively. Can you edit the post with the updated code?

Comment: Ok so I just changed so that I calculate the correlation using log returns as well and now I have something which looks feasible @slothrop Thank you so much for helping me with this :D 

Check this out: https://prnt.sc/RStO7_sxTKwM

Also I just updated the code, could u pls check so it looks correct? Only updated the lines before the for loop fyi

Comment: @ES100 cool, that looks much closer! (1) With `pct_change` you are using linear returns rather than log (the difference will not be large when daily returns are small). Log returns would be the natural logarithm of `(1 + df["stock"].pct_change)` (2) Ideally for the numbers on your axes, you would have annualised returns and annualised volatility.

Comment: Based on your description of the problem, Shouldn't the loop step by 0.05, not 0.001? (`for x in np.arange(0, 1.00, 0.05):`)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07'],
    'AMZN': [3485.41, 3450.19, 3485.45, 3479.15, 3482.88],
    'PFIZER': [43.75, 44.39, 44.07, 44.24, 44.32]
})

df['AMZN'] = df['AMZN'].astype(float)
df['PFIZER'] = df['PFIZER'].astype(float)


df['amzn_returns'] = df['AMZN'].pct_change()
df['pfizer_returns'] = df['PFIZER'].pct_change()

stdev_amzn = df['amzn_returns'].std()
stdev_pfizer = df['pfizer_returns'].std()

return_amzn = df['amzn_returns'].mean()
return_pfizer = df['pfizer_returns'].mean()

correlation = df['amzn_returns'].corr(df['pfizer_returns'])
talj = stdev_pfizer**2 - (stdev_amzn * stdev_pfizer * correlation)
namn = stdev_amzn**2 + stdev_pfizer**2 - (2 * stdev_amzn * stdev_pfizer * correlation)
print("Minimum variance portfolio: ", talj/namn)


returns = []
stdevs = []
for x in np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.05):
    w_amzn = x
    w_pfizer = 1 - x
    portfolio_return = (w_amzn * return_amzn) + (w_pfizer * return_pfizer)
    portfolio_stdev = np.sqrt((w_amzn ** 2) * (stdev_amzn ** 2) + (w_pfizer ** 2) * (stdev_pfizer ** 2) + 2 * w_amzn * w_pfizer * correlation * stdev_amzn * stdev_pfizer)
    returns.append(portfolio_return)
    stdevs.append(portfolio_stdev)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=stdevs, y=returns, name='Efficient Frontier'))
fig.update_layout(title='Efficient Frontier', xaxis_title='Standard Deviation', yaxis_title='Mean Return')
fig.show()
```

which gives

[image]